# Can we delete file from SFTP Import folder after import activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automation, activities, import

Can we delete file from SFTP Import folder after import activity?

I have an automation that picks up the file based on name. The file is uploaded frequently on SFTP import folder and I have noticed an issue.

When we upload a new file, old file is read by the automation / import activity because file name is in same format except date.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I saw some posts on this and I don't think it's possible to delete the file programmatically

Comment: Is it normal for import activity to consume older file? Is there any way to solve that problem if we cannot delete the file from import folder? Any workaround? Right now my automation is looking for : file name contains....

Comment: @kuml In the advanced settings you can configure rules to not consume a file if it is older than a set time frame.

Comment: @TravisNaughton Advanced settings of what? automation studio? Import activity?

Comment: I checked import definition and these are the only options I see (there is no option to NOT consume a file if it is order than a set time): 
 Advanced File Options
 Skip if last import occurred less than the following number of hours ago:   
0
 Fail import if file is older than the following number of hours:   
0
 System buffer (hours):

Comment: @kuml yes those are the settings travis is talking about. You may be able to trick the system using a different file naming pattern for overlapping files or different drop folders.

Comment: Are you using the `%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%`, or some derivative, personalization string in the import activity?

Comment: @garek007 can you please give an example?

Comment: @Gortonington I am using an automation that is set to trigger by a file drop and within the automation I have an import activity. I have the fila format set as "filename_%%year%%%%date%%%%month%%" and when I drop a new file with new date, the automation is pickup up an older file. If I have to delete file manually then it defeats the whole purpose of having an automation.

Comment: @kuml I was thinking of this post as an example https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186705/automation-studio-sftp-file-drop-trigger-to-import-activity

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom Data Extract activity type available called "Delete File From ET FTP or Safehouse", and that will allow you delete a file from the FTP site.  However, it will only allow you to delete files from Safehouse or the Import or Export folders; no other File Locations.